# Mule - Set properties on spring object call in Mule flow

Tags: java, spring, mule, mule-el

I'm using Mule 3.3.CE

I have a Class called SpringObject which implements Callable interface

```
package com.threads.test;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class SpringObject implements Callable {

    private String someData;
    public String getSomeData() {
        return someData;
    }

    public void setSomeData(String someData) {
        this.someData = someData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("CALL SPRING --->>"+someData);

        return eventContext.getMessage();
    }

}
```

And my flow is

```
<http:connector name="httpConnectorEntryPoint" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS"/>

<spring:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
<spring:bean id="component" name="component" class="com.threads.test.SpringObject" lazy-init="false">   
</spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="TestThreadsFlow1" doc:name="TestThreadsFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8099" path="m" connector-ref="httpConnectorEntryPoint" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[&quot;ExitA&quot;]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="component">
                <property key="someData" value="Information"/>
            </spring-object>
        </component>
    </flow>
```

The problem is that when I run my flow and use the http connector, the console shows

CALL SPRING --->>null

instead of

CALL SPRING --->>Information

What could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to configure your spring bean outside the flow as follow:

```
<spring:bean id="component" name="component"
    class="com.threads.test.SpringObject" lazy-init="false">
    <spring:property name="someData" value="Information" />
</spring:bean>

and inside the flow do:

<component>
    <spring-object bean="component" />
</component>
```

Comment: Why the repeated answer?

Answer (score 2):

From the property element description in the XSD:

> Sets a Mule property. This is a name/value pair that can be set on
>   components, services, etc., and which   provide a generic way of
>   configuring the system. Typically, you shouldn't need to use a generic
>   property like   this, since almost all functionality is exposed via
>   dedicated elements. However, it can be useful in   configuring obscure
>   or overlooked options and in configuring transports from the generic
>   endpoint elements.

This means it's not intended for what you are trying to use it. The appropriate way to set a property in your bean is as follows:

```
<spring:bean id="component" name="component" class="com.threads.test.SpringObject" lazy-init="false">
    <spring:property name="someData" value="Information"/>
</spring:bean>
```